# Core Data - detect equal properties in fetched objects

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My core data model:

```
Contact
=======

name
phone number (unique)
```

I need to display a table view of contacts with the following condition:

if there is more than one contact with the same **name** - show name+number
otherwise - show only name

Fo for example, if my core data contacts are:

```
Michael, 11112221  
Jon, 33438282  
Jon, 72727272  
Lisa, 99939393
```

My table view should present:

```
Jon (33438282)  
Jon (72727272) 
Lisa   
Michael
```

Currently I'm using the following NSFetchRequest to show the contact list:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Contact"];
request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
request.fetchBatchSize = 20;

self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                    managedObjectContext:context
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:@"nameFirstLetter"
                                                                               cacheName:nil];
```

**I'm looking for the most efficient way** to know which name appears more than once so I can show the number next to the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `NSSQLiteStoreType` as your persistent store you can fetch duplicate items with an NSExpression:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity        = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSAttributeDescription *nameDesc   = [entity.attributesByName objectForKey:@"name"];
NSExpression *keyPathExpression    = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"name"];
NSExpression *countExpression      = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"count:" arguments:@[keyPathExpression]];

NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[expressionDescription setName: @"count"];
[expressionDescription setExpression: countExpression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType: NSInteger32AttributeType];

NSError *error = nil;
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Contact"];
[fetch setPropertiesToFetch:@[nameDesc, expressionDescription]];
[fetch setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[nameDesc]];
[fetch setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
NSArray *duplicates = [results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"count > 1"]]; 
NSArray *duplicateNames = [duplicates valueForKeyPath:@"name"];
```

`duplicateNames` contains the name of contacts which name appears multiple times in the db. So, whenever a contact displayed in the table view, just query the `duplicateNames` array to check whether the actual contact is a duplicate or not.

Answer (score 1):

The **easiest** way if you only want to modify the display I would modify `tableView:cellForRowAt...` to check the name of the person above and below the current one

in basic mock code:

```
- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:(id)path {
    ....
    Person *prior = ...
    Person *next = ...

    if(prior.name == current.name || next.name == current.name) {
        //show name+number
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for you reply, but I can't use that approach. I didn't mentioned it in my question, but I have more than one section, this other section also show contacts but not all. so if the user didn't scrolled to this contact in my main section, I have a problem

Comment: I think I must do another fetch, I just wonder what would be the most efficient.

Comment: :D yes you didn't mention that .. but for that I will show you the most elegant way!

Comment: actually vbalis way looks nice. rerun the query whenever you modify the DB